# Fast imperfect match algorithm against multiple targets

Tags: algorithm

Lets say I have a set `S`, with elements which are N-tuples, i.e.`(xi1, xi2, ... , xin)`.

Given elements `x = (x1, x2, ..., xn)` and `y = (y1, y2, ..., yn)`, `matches(x,y,M)` if and only if at least `M` elements of `x` and `y` are equal.

Now given a set `S`, `matchSet(x,S,M)` returns the elements of `S` which `matches(x,y,M)` is true.

Assuming that `S` has data such that `matchSet` will on average match only 0 or 1 elements (it will occasionally match more, but rarely), is there a way to write `matchSet` and structure `S` so that it's running time is sub linear to the size of S, and it's space is reasonable (i.e. not putting `2^L` indexes on `S` where `L` is the length of the elements)?

Alternatively, a fast running `matchManySet(S', S, M)` would also be acceptable, which runs `matchSet` for every element of `S'`, also long as it takes significantly less time than the size of `S` times the size of `S'`.

Comment: You've rejected having 2^L indices, but how about L^2 indices? When you say that elements "rarely" match in more than 1 element, how rarely are we talking? Specifically: if you perform L^2 lookups -- one to find elements with (y1,y2)=(x1,x2), one to find elements with (y1,y3)=(x1,x3), etc. -- will that give you overall sublinear time?

Comment: No, they rarely match more than one thing in the set. So if I'm trying to match 5 out of 10, they'll almost always be only on match of 5, but there may be lots of matches of 2 and 3 for example

Answer (score 0):

This task sounds very interesting for me. I have some idea, unfortunately somebody should test it (I have no time for its implementation). Data structure for storing such tuples reminds me suffix tree. (For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).

As example, you can store set Sx in one suffix tree, Sy in other suffix tree. In such case, your task boils down to creation result suffix tree via merging given two trees (of course, during merge you should use specific predicate like whether tuples have `K` occurences). Overall algorithm complexity will be `O(N + M)`, where `N`, `M` are sizes of input suffix trees.

I hope such idea will help you.

EDIT: This idea has strong restriction - lexicographic order on tuples